# React/Redux Saga: Need to trigger a route change after user clicks button on form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux-saga, react-hooks

I'm working on a project that was built using Redux Saga. I have a component that features a group of offers each with their own button to select that specific offer. This component lives on page 1 of 4 and I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a redirect to the next page after the user clicks a selection, but I have no idea how to do this within the context of Redux or Redux Saga. I've included both the navigation handler and my component below. I started to edit the navigation component with a proposed action *UPDATE_PAGE:* but I'm not sure I'm even heading down the right path. Any suggestions/explanations or code samples on how to do this would be hugely appreciated

`Offer Component`

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import NavigationContainer from '../../containers/NavigationContainer'
import RouteLoader from '../../components/core/RouteLoader'
import { getCustomer } from '../../actions/customer'
import { routerPropTypes, routePropTypes } from '../../propTypes'

class OrdersRoutes extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    customer: PropTypes.object,
    getCustomer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    routes: routePropTypes,
    ...routerPropTypes
  }

  getAppData = data => {
    this.props.getCustomer(data)
  }

  render() {
    const { match, customer } = this.props
    const { offers: offersRoute, ...routes } = this.props.routes

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navigation>
          <Route
            path={match.path}
            component={NavigationContainer}
          />
        </Navigation>
        <PageContainer>
          <Switch>
            <RouteLoader
              exact
              path={`${match.path}${offersRoute.path}`}
              component={offersRoute.component}
              shouldLoad={customer !== undefined}
              onLoad={this.getAppData}
            />
            {Object.values(routes).map(
              ({
                path, id, component, disabled
              }) =>
                !disabled && (
                  <Route
                    exact
                    key={id}
                    path={`${match.path}${path}`}
                    component={component}
                  />
                )
            )}
            <Redirect to={`${match.path}${offersRoute.path}`} />
          </Switch>
        </PageContainer>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const Navigation = styled.div`
  padding: 0 10px;
`

const PageContainer = styled.div`
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  routes: state.navigation.pages.orders.routes,
  customer: state.customer.details
})

const mapDispatchToProps = { getCustomer }

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(OrdersRoutes)
```

`Navigation Component`

```
import * as pages from '../constants/pages'

export const initialState = {
  pages: {
    ...pages
  }
}

function navigationReducer(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    UPDATE_PAGE: {
      const { id, page } = payload

      return {
        ...state,
        pages: {
          ...state.pages,
          [id]: {
            ...state.pages[id],
            ...page
          }
        }
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

export default navigationReducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to include react-router's history into the payload of UPDATE_PAGE.

So 1) we wrap a component which triggers this action withRouter. This gives us access to history as a prop; 2) when dispatching UPDATE_PAGE, include history as a payload in addition to id and page 3) in redux-saga perform a redirect on every UPDATE_PAGE:

```
yield takeEvery(UPDATE_PAGE, function*(action){ action.payload.history.push('/new-route'); })
```

Comment: I was able to figure this out by altering the function in a separate component page like this ```handleSelectOffer = offer => {
    const { location, history } = this.props
    this.props.selectOffer(offer)
    history.push(`${location.pathname.replace('offers', 'configure')}`)
  }```

I now need to setup a Redux Saga to track errors and block the redirect if there are any errors/missing fields on the page. I'll set up a separate question for this. Thank you for your help!